# problem Insert Data Into the Table Using Node.js and MySQL

Tags: mysql, node.js

I have a problem inserting data in the table from my HTML form on the site.
if you could help me I'll be thankful.
here are my codes:

users.js:

```js
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();
const db = require("../database");

router.get("/form", (req, res, next) => {
  res.render("users.ejs");
});

router.post("/create", (req, res, next) => {
  let userDetails = req.body;
  let sql = "insert into users set ?";
  db.query(sql, userDetails, (err, results, fields) => {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log("user data inserted successfully");
  });
 
  res.redirect("back");
});

module.exports = router;
```

users.ejs:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class='user-detail'>
        <h2>create user data</h2>
        <form action="/users/create" method="post">
            <label>Full Name</label>
            <input type="text" placeholder="enter fullname" name="fullName" required>
            <label>Email Address</label>
            <input type="email" placeholder="enter email address" name="emailAddress" required>
            <label>City</label>
            <input type="text" placeholder="enter full city" name="city">
            <label>Country</label>
            <input type="text" placeholder="enter full country" name="country">
            <button type="submit">Submit</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

error:

PS C:\Users\yaran\Desktop\mysql.ejs.node> node app.js
server is running on port=3000..
database connected successfully!
C:\Users\yaran\Desktop\mysql.ejs.node\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Parser.js:437
throw err; // Rethrow non-MySQL errors
^

Error: ER_PARSE_ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '?' at line 1
at Query.Sequence._packetToError (C:\Users\yaran\Desktop\mysql.ejs.node\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\sequences\Sequence.js:47:14)
at Query.ErrorPacket (C:\Users\yaran\Desktop\mysql.ejs.node\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\sequences\Query.js:79:18)
at Protocol._parsePacket (C:\Users\yaran\Desktop\mysql.ejs.node\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:291:23)
at Parser._parsePacket (C:\Users\yaran\Desktop\mysql.ejs.node\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Parser.js:433:10)
at Parser.write (C:\Users\yaran\Desktop\mysql.ejs.node\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Parser.js:43:10)
at Protocol.write (C:\Users\yaran\Desktop\mysql.ejs.node\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:38:16)
at Socket. (C:\Users\yaran\Desktop\mysql.ejs.node\node_modules\mysql\lib\Connection.js:88:28)
at Socket. (C:\Users\yaran\Desktop\mysql.ejs.node\node_modules\mysql\lib\Connection.js:526:10)
at Socket.emit (node:events:527:28)
at addChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:315:12)
--------------------
at Protocol._enqueue (C:\Users\yaran\Desktop\mysql.ejs.node\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:144:48)
at Connection.query (C:\Users\yaran\Desktop\mysql.ejs.node\node_modules\mysql\lib\Connection.js:198:25)
at C:\Users\yaran\Desktop\mysql.ejs.node\routes\users.js:12:6
at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\yaran\Desktop\mysql.ejs.node\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
at next (C:\Users\yaran\Desktop\mysql.ejs.node\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:144:13)
at Route.dispatch (C:\Users\yaran\Desktop\mysql.ejs.node\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:114:3)
at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\yaran\Desktop\mysql.ejs.node\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
at C:\Users\yaran\Desktop\mysql.ejs.node\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:284:15
at Function.process_params (C:\Users\yaran\Desktop\mysql.ejs.node\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:346:12)
at next (C:\Users\yaran\Desktop\mysql.ejs.node\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:280:10) {
code: 'ER_PARSE_ERROR',
errno: 1064,
sqlMessage: "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '?' at line 1",
sqlState: '42000',
index: 0,
sql: 'insert into users set ?'
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case your `req.body` really hold only one variable, you have to put it in square brackets.

```
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();
const db = require("../database");
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
router.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

router.get("/form", (req, res, next) => {
  res.render("users.ejs");
});

router.post("/create", (req, res, next) => {
  let userDetails = req.body;
  console.log(userDetails);
  let sql = "insert into users set ?";
  db.query(sql, [userDetails], (err, results, fields) => {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log("user data inserted successfully");
  });
 
  res.redirect("back");
});

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: when i do that it gave me this error:                                                                                  code: 'ER_PARSE_ERROR',
  errno: 1064,
  sqlMessage: "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'NULL' at line 1",
  sqlState: '42000',
  index: 0,
  sql: 'insert into users set NULL'

Comment: try to use `console.log(req.body);` to se wich variable you get

maybe you get "dtail" as variable, try to use `let userDetails = req.body.detail;`

Comment: it shows undefined even console.log(userDetails) too.    my way of doing this is right? or it's better to change it?

Comment: i have update my answer, please try to use this code. I have added the bodyparser

Answer (score 0):

> syntax to use near '?' at line 1

seems to come from:

```
insert into users set ?
```

I see 2 problems:

- There is no insert syntax that has simply "set ..." at the end if an insert.  (Study MySQL more.)
- `db.query()` failed to replace the "?".  (Study node.js more)